# I've got to update a column in one SQL table with a counter stored in another table, and update that table too

Tags: sql, counter, increment

I'm using SQL server 2005 (for testing) & 2007 (for production).

I have to add a unique record ID to all the records in my table, in an existing column, using a "last record ID" column from another table.  So, I'm going to do some sort of `UPDATE` of my table, but I have to get the "last record ID" from the other table, increment it, update THAT table and then update my record.

Can anyone give me an example of how to do this?  Other users may be incrementing the counter also.

Answer (score 3):

if you are INSERTING into one table and then UPDATE(ing) the next table you can use @@IDENTITY to give you the auto increment ID from the first table.

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (description) VALUES ('blah');
UPDATE table2 SET (tabel1ID = @@IDENTITY) WHERE condition
```

@@IDENTITY will give you the ID of the last inserted row.

Comment: Thank you, JD.  But no, I'm not inserting it.  I need to get the "next user ID" from row 1 of Table1, increment and update that column in row 1 of Table1 with "next user ID + 1" and insert that into row 1 of table 2, then repeat for next row of Table 2 until no more rows.  But I'm always only updating Row 1 of Table 1.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info... e.g. DB Schema then we may be able to help a bit more...

Comment: OK.. so my take on your problem (And let me know if it is wrong):

1. You have table1 which has a 'userID' column.
2. You want to make 'userID' = userID + 1.
3. You then want to insert this new 'userID' into table 2.

Do you need to use SQL? This might be easier to implement using a secondary language (such as C# or PHP or your favourite language) in a foreach loop.

If you need to use SQL use a 'while begin end' loop...

There are plenty of good tutorials on 'foreach' (and in SQL 'while begin end') loops in both SQL and other languages on Google :)

Hope this helps a little... Shout if not